# Data binding to a variable of an object

Tags: wpf, ironpython

I'm planning to bind a textbox to a variable of an object

How am I going to do this ?

eg.

```
<TextBox x:Name="MaxCurrent_Tb" Margin="84,53,0,0" FontFamily="Roboto Light" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsReadOnly="True" MaxLines="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="123"/>

class mainWindow(Window) :
    wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'TPC_Main.xaml')
    sampler = DMMSampler()
    self.MaxCurrent_Tb.Text = sampler.max_current
```

I'm planning to bind max_current of this sampler object,

and max_current is update frequently, how do I binding this varible for real time?

I have set DataContext to another variable, so I can't set DataContext to

sampler, is there anyother way to bind to this sampler object for real time ?

Comment: Sure, make `sampler` a public property of the view model, i.e. the object in the DataContext. Then just set `Text="{Binding sampler.max_current}"`.

Comment: @Clemens I have tried that.. but the textbox does't changed, however if I passed view model to sampler class, and set max_current in sampler class, then it works, why is this happening ?

Comment: No idea, you haven't shown your code. Note that all elements in a Binding Path must be public properties, and if the Binding is supposed to be updated when a property value changes, the class that owns the property must implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.